# Find $x \in \mathbb Z^+$ such that $x\sum _{i=1}^{x} \frac 1{i!} \in \mathbb Z$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find $x \in \mathbb Z^+$ such that 
$$n = x\cdot \left ( \frac 1{1!} + \frac 1{2!} + \cdots +\frac 1{x!} \right )  \in \mathbb Z$$

---

It is easy to show $x = 1$ is a solution,

But I don't know what to do to find all the $x$, please give me a hint.

Thank you !

Comment: The following is likely gross overkill. Use Bertrand's Postulate (a theorem since the $1850$'s) which says that for $n\ge 2$ there always is a prime strictly between $n$ and $2n$. (You will have to take care of a few small $x$ by hand.)

Comment: At least for even $x$, the only solution should be $x=2$, because
$
x\cdot \left ( \frac 1{1!} + \frac 1{2!} + \cdots +\frac 1{x!} \right )=\frac{x!+\frac{x!}{2}+...+x+1}{(x-1)!}
$
whose numerator is odd, while its denominator is even, if $x > 2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
x\cdot \left ( \frac 1{1!} + \frac 1{2!} + \cdots +\frac 1{x!} \right )=\frac{x!+\frac{x!}{2}+...+x+1}{(x-1)!}
$$
and for $x > 3$, the numerator is never divisible by $3$, while the denominator...

Hence, the only solutions are...

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}2\cdot\sum_{i=1}^2\frac1{i!}&=2\left(1+\frac12\right)=3\in\Bbb Z\\
3\cdot\sum_{i=1}^3\frac1{i!}&=3\left(1+\frac12+\frac16\right)=3+\frac32+\frac12=5\in\Bbb Z\end{align*}$$

Comment: Those are all, no?

Comment: Yup, I think so, but I haven't yet worked it out.